# Error in edit button "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string StudentNo = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
  frmEdit EditForm = new frmEdit();
  EditForm.StudentNo;
  EditForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If `StudentNo` is a property you have to do something with it, for example assign it to a variable.

Comment: why the line `EditForm.StudentNo;`

Comment: Your function should start with an opening brace, `{` not a closing one `}`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `EditForm.StudentNo;` syntax? Do you want to assign some value to `EditForm.StudentNo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to write

```
EditForm.StudentNo = StudentNo;
```

instead of just

```
EditForm.StudentNo;
```